# How to find if a string in a list is an extension of another string with wild card *

Tags: java

**Problem:** Given a list of wild card strings(wild card is a * which is always at the end of a string), determine if the list has strings that are extension of another wild card string in the list.

Examples:

1. [abc.*, abc.def.* ]

- the list has field abc.def.* which is an extension of abc.*

2. [abc.xyz.*, def.*]

- the list has unique wildcard fields.

How can I achieve this efficiently in Java ? I know I can do it with two loops. Tried o(n^2) solution. Looking for an efficient way to reduce the time complexity. Any thoughts ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the format of the string? Would a wildcard appear only at the end of the string?

Comment: Your "Since..." sentence seems contradictory. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: @Command Master - yes wildcard only appears at the end.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - if abc.* exists in a list there cannot be another string which is an extension of it for eg: abc.def.*

Comment: The two clauses of the or seem to say the same thing, though one is "detect" and the other "return false".

Comment: @YvesDaoust - I removed 'or'. Basically I need to detect if there exists a string which is an extension of another string with wildcard at the end.

Comment: Possibly with a prefix tree.

Comment: What exactly is the problem statement?  Please specify the inputs and the desired output, in a general form.  An example is not a substitute for a specification of the problem.  Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source, or explain the motivation?  Please don't reply in the comments; we don't want someone to have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Instead, [edit] the post based on the feedback so it is self-contained and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Comment: @D.W. Updated problem statement along with examples. Hope that helps. I have been editing the original post as well as commenting.

Comment: Thank you!  Please proof-read the question -- Markdown interprets '*' in a way you probably are not expecting.  You can use a code environment (`\`abc*\``) or use a backslash (`abc\*`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), also known as a prefix tree.  The running time will be (approximately) linear in the size of the input.